# Using array of numbers to toggle radio button visibility. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, radio-button

I have an array of numbers that can be 1-24. ($timelist) I want to use this array to make a select time form. How would I use this array to toggle the visibility of a radio button?

For example: I have array(1,2,4) and radio buttons 1AM, 2AM, 3AM, and 4AM. I want radio button 3AM to not show based on the array in my php script.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

What I got so far is a form where the user selects a date and hits enter.

It then sends them to a php file named validate.php via get method.

The script will do it's job and place available times into an array.

I want to use that array (1-24) to display the available times as radio buttons (12AM to 12PM) where the user can select one based on a time available and continue the application process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$timelist = array( 1, 2, 4 );
foreach($timelist as $time):
    echo "<input type='radio' name='time' value='$time' /> $radio AM<br />";
endforeach;
```

Something like that, you mean?

Edit: to have nice formatting, you could do something along the lines of

```
$time%12 . ( $time >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM' )
```

Comment: $time%12 . ( $time >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM' ) makes 12am and 12pm display as 0pm

Comment: ($time == 0 or $time == 12) ? '12' . $time%12

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that you initially do send the radio input to the client in the response HTML, and you want to hide it afterwards? This doesn't make much sense - simply prepare the response HTML according to the elements in the array, instead of rendering everything and than hiding it. Do something like:

```
<?php foreach ($timelist as $time): ?>
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="<?php echo $time?>" /> <?php echo $time?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

for military time inclusion try this

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php while ($i <= 24): ?>
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" /> 
    <?php echo (12 < $i ? $i .' AM': ($i -12).' PM'); >
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on echo (12 < $time ? $time.' AM': $time-12.' PM');

Comment: You're missing an `$i++`, and you never set the `$time` variable to anything. The syntax error is because `$time-12` should be wrapped in `()`, `($time-12).' PM'`